# Sum of numbers not showing

Tags: c

I have just started C and already ran into this problem. The program should accept the integers that the user's inputs and as soon as the user inputs -1 the program quits and displays the sum of all the integers entered. The only trouble I am having is that it's displaying the sum as 0 for some reason even though I did the math bit underneath "Sum is". Any help is much appreciated.

```
int x;
int sum = 0;

printf("Please enter some integers man\n");

do
{
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
} while (x != -1);

printf("\n");

printf("Sum is: %d ", sum);
sum = sum + x;

printf("\n");
```

Comment: You ignore the input, calculate sum as 0-1 and expect to see what in the output done even before the calculation?

Comment: If you don't calculate the sum inside the loop, how would it accumulate anything ?

Comment: You should have your sum=sum+x statement inside the while loop. Not after printing the value

Comment: the only problem is that its showing 1 less from the expected output. like if I do 6+4 its shows 9 instead of 10

Comment: You just invalidated your question and the correct answer, by editing your shown code to apply the proposed answer.. Please undo that.

Comment: I rolled back to the original question - as the answers/comments did not make any sense any more with the edit

Comment: It was already done for you. Please ask in a comment, if you do not understand why.

Comment: Also, in the (now rolled-back) update, you add -1 to sum. Don't do the add if `x == -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the sum of numbers you should add them in while loop.
So your line of code

```
 sum = sum+x;
```

Should be places in do while

```
 do
 {
     scanf("%d",&x);
     sum = sum+x;
 }while(x!=-1);
```

But now you added -1 in your sum and i doubt you want that, so you should add 1 to sum after do while

```
 do
 {
     scanf("%d",&x);
     sum = sum+x;
 }while(x!=-1);
 sum = sum+1;
```

Or instead use while loop

```
 x=0;
 while(x!=-1)
 { 
      scanf("%d",&x);
      sum=sum+x;
  }
```

Comment: he edited his question. when i read it his do while loop was like this

Comment: do
{
scanf_s("%d", &x);
     sum = x + sum;
}
while(x!=-1);

Comment: Why not add error checking - i.e. check the return value from `scanf_s` and propose a solution if the user has not typed in a number

Comment: This adds `-1` to `sum` when the use enters it. Don't think OP wants that. (Even though answer has been accepted).

Comment: Changing to while does not help. Moving the sum into the loop does. Adding the -1 into the sum seems unlikely to be the goal. I know you fell vicitim to the edit applying the other answer, but you should still explain which you recommend while, or change it. Also please clarify whether OP really wants the -1 added...

Comment: @Kobe Accepting this seems to indicate that you actually want the -1 added into the sum. This is of course your decision. It seems so unlikely however, that it would be worth explicitly stating that you are aware of it and really want it...

Comment: Subtracting another 1 from the sum which is already containing an unneeded -1 is not improving things.

Comment: 1. Please read the manual page for `scanf` and its friends. (i.e. `sscanf` is wrong. 2. Please consider the return value from `scanf` and its family of functions. It is important.

Answer (score 3):

You only add `x` to sum once and that's after you print it out. Move adding `x` to `sum` into the loop.

You also need to make sure you don't add the `-1` which likely acts only as a condition ending the loop and not a term you want to add.

Comment: this isn't entirely correct.  Just moving the addition statement inside the loop will also include the terminal `-1` value in the sum, which is likely not intended.

Comment: @bruceg That's correct, thought it'd be obvious enough for OP after testing. Edited the answer for completeness.

Comment: Please read the comments above ( Aleksa Jovanovic) - They equally appply

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by Jacek, here is the detail to get an efficient summing without the final adding of -1 and without additional `if`:

```
int x=0;
int s=0;
/* ... */
do
{
    sum = x + sum; /* first time x==0, no effect */
    s=scanf_s("%d", &x); /* note scan success */
} while ((x != -1) && (s==1)); /* also quit on scan failure */

/* do not sum = x + sum; anywhere outside of the loop */
```

Comment: Please check the return value from `scanf_s`